# Calculate area between the min of two curves, and the x axis

Tags: php, python, interpolation

I have two datasets (represented by blue and red curves):
[image: see figure]

Each dataset is composed by a data and a timestamp.
The timestep variation (space between two data) are 
1. not the same in each dataset
2. is not constant.

My wish: calculate the area of the green part of this graph with python or php. Have you got an idea?

Thank you

Comment: You can easily characterize the curve by using the `min` function - But my question is, do you have any constraints on the programme -run time, storage execution etc

Comment: Ok for the min function but the issue is how can i perform this on two arrays where the timestamp are not the same and are not constant?

Comment: Find all the x values of both functions by including in the same array the x values of each of them. Then, for each of the functions, iterate this new array and associate an y coordinate to each x value as the original y value if x was in the original set of x values, or its interpolated value for the current function. Finally, iterate again all the x values and associate to it the min of both y values computed before.

Answer (score 0):

FTR, here is my solution:
Concatenate the two x vector

```
x_out=numpy.concatenate((x1,x2),axis=0)
```

Sort the output vector of x

```
x_out=numpy.sort(x_out)
```

Interpolate (and/or extrapolate) the y1 and y2

```
y_total_1=numpy.interp(x_out,x1,y1)
```

and finally take the minimum of the two output vector and perform the calcul of the area trhout trapz

```
mini=numpy.minimum(y_total_1,y_total_2);

Area_minimal=numpy.trapz(mini,x_out)
```